# Parsing a homogenous polymorphic json array

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a data type where one of the fields is a list of **one** of `n` other data types (`n` is small and the types are known in advance). I would like to make a JSON parser but I can't quite figure it out. I've tried creating a Pet type class and making them both instances of it, but it seemed to be a dead end. Any help would be appreciated!

As a simplified example - I have a `Person` data type who can have a list of pets, either dogs *or* cats - but not a mix of both.

Here's the example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)
import Control.Monad (mzero)

data Person = Person {
  name :: String,
  species :: String,
  pets :: [?] -- a list of dogs OR cats
} deriving Show

instance FromJSON (Person a) where
  parseJSON (Object v) = ???

data Dog = Dog {
  dogField :: String
} deriving Show

 instance FromJSON Dog where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Dog <$>
    v .: "dogField"

data Cat = Cat {
  catField :: String
} deriving Show

instance FromJSON Cat where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Cat <$>
    v .: "catField"
```

Comment: Is it essential to your requirements that `pets` doesn't have cats and dogs at the same time, or is it just a simplifying assumption?

Comment: Maybe not essential, but it reflects my current data model. But a solution without that assumption would also be great!

Comment: If you actually want to separate cats and dogs, the natural thing to do is having separate lists of different types in `Person`.

Comment: Hmm that would work - I'm serializing it to + from a postgres json field as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard way of representing either one type or another is to use the `Either` type, e.g.:

```
data Person { ..., pets :: Either [Dog] [Cat] }
```

Also, you might be interested in use GHC Generics to auto-derive the To/FromJSON instances.

An example with a data structure that uses `Either`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data Person = Person {
  name :: String,
  species :: String,
  pets :: Either [String] [Int]
} deriving (Show,Generic)

instance ToJSON Person    -- instances are auto-derived    
instance FromJSON Person

doit = do
  let me = Person "user5402" "Human" (Right [42])
  print $ encode me
```

If you have more than two alternatives you can easily create your own sum type like this:

```
-- assume the possible pet types are: Dog, Cat, Rodent, Reptile
data Pets = Dogs [Dog] | Cats [Cat] | Rodents [Rodent] | Reptiles [Reptile]
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Person { ..., pets :: Pets }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

doit = do
  let me = Person "user5402" "Human" (Rodents [agerbil, amouse])
  print $ encode me
```

where `agerbil` and `amouse` are `Rodent` values.

Comment: @sportanova: You described your cats and dogs as "one of n other data types (n is small and the types are known in advance)". In such cases you almost never need to create a class, and a sum type (that is, a type with multiple constructors) is often the easiest alternative. `Either` is a standard way of making a sum type for two possibilities.

Comment: user5402 @duplode thanks! I ended up using a modified version of your answer to remove the "content" and "tag" fields from the Generic ToJSON / FromJSON - see below

Answer (score 1):

I'm modifying @user5402's answer because I don't like the "tag" and "contents" fields that Generics added. Also accepting his answer since he gave me the key insight of how to structure the sum type

```
instance FromJSON Pets where
  parseJSON (Object o) = (parsePets o "pets")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

parsePets :: Object -> T.Text -> Parser Pets
parsePets o key = case H.lookup key o of
               Nothing -> fail $ "key " ++ show key ++ " not present"
               Just v  -> parseToCatsOrDogs (o .: "species") v
{-# INLINE parsePets #-}

parseToCatsOrDogs :: Parser String -> Value -> Parser Pets
parseToCatsOrDogs speciesParser (Array v) = speciesParser >>= \species -> case species of
  "dog" -> (V.mapM (\x -> parseJSON $ x) v) >>= \ dogVector -> return $ Dogs (V.toList dogVector)
  "cat" -> (V.mapM (\x -> parseJSON $ x) v) >>= \ catVector -> return $ Cats (V.toList catVector)
  _ -> mzero
parseToCatsOrDogs _ _ = mzero
```